# Text IO Stream Number Format Exception

Tags: java, ios, exception, text-files, number-formatting

I've been programming Monopoly on java and I've been running into a NumberFormatException when I pull the rent values from a .txt file.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Here's the code:

```
try{
    //Searching for .txt file
    fileName = "N://java/Monopoly/src/rent.txt";

    //creating FileReader and BuffReader objects
    FileReader input = new FileReader(fileName);

    BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);

    //reading first line
    String line = bufRead.readLine();

    while(line!=""){

        //not sure why, but program doesn't run well without if statement
        if(line!=""){

            //creating array of in variable
            splitArr = line.split(",");

            //creating rent object
            rent r = new rent(Integer.parseInt(splitArr[0]),Integer.parseInt(splitArr[1]),Integer.parseInt(splitArr[2]),Integer.parseInt(splitArr[3]),Integer.parseInt(splitArr[4]),Integer.parseInt(splitArr[5]));

            //storing rent object to a public static Arraylist holding all rents for the game
            rents.add(r);

            //debugging code that has been commented out
            //System.out.println(r.toString());
        }

        //debugging code that has been commented out
        /*for(String s : splitArr){
            System.out.print(s+", ");
        }*/

        //reading next line
        line = bufRead.readLine();

    }
    //closing IO stream
    bufRead.close();

//preventing out of bounds exception error   
}catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    System.out.println("Usage: java ReadFile filename: rent\n");  

//preventing IOException error
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();

//I can't quite remember I have this in there. I know it didn't work right without it at some point
}catch(NullPointerException e){

}
```

When I uncomment the enhanced for loop at line 16, I get some values followed by the error and then all of the rest of the values as if there was no problem. I have noticed that when I delete and re-enter the values where the error begins, the error moves to other places. I've checked the arguments in the rent class (it requires 6 int's) and have checked the .txt file where all the values are good.
How do I fix this or should I not worry about it and add another catch statement to ignore the error?

Comment: You're comparing strings with `!=`. You should use `!line.equals("")`.

Comment: Not going to lie, I'm a little annoyed with myself that I didn't notice this earlier. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing strings with !=. You should use !line.equals(""). – Saviour Self